# Particular solution of $y''-2y'+y=\frac{e^x}{x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have second-order linear differential equation with constant coefficients:
$$y''-2y'+y=\frac{e^x}{x^2}$$

I know how to solve this using variation of parameters. But I know I can "guess" particular solution for some functions. So is there a known form of particular solution if I have $f(x)=\frac{e^x}{x^2}$?

Comment: The Guess method is called method of undetermined coefficient.

Comment: Why do you have to guess? The characteristic equation $$r^2-2r+1=0$$ suggests the change of variable $$y(x)=e^xz(x)$$ and then the differential equation to solve becomes $$z''(x)=\frac1{x^2}$$ which you might be able to solve... In two steps, $$z'(x)=-\frac1x+a$$ hence $$z(x)=-\log x+ax+b$$ which yields $$y(x)=e^x(-\log x+ax+b)$$

Comment: @Did, why isn't this an answer?

Comment: @Chickenmancer 1. Because I am going a little fast in it and that my hope, each time, is that the OP rephrases and expands this into a full answer. 2. And because such precise indications given in comments have a "natural" tendency to be converted into full answers by other users...

Answer (score 4):

Hint. Note that
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(e^{-x}y(x)\right)=
\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x}(y'(x)-y(x))\right)
=e^{-x}(y''(x)-2y'(x)+y(x)).$$
Therefore it remains to solve
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(e^{-x}y(x)\right)=\frac{1}{x^2}.$$

Comment: Really nice....